# Android app widget size problems

Tags: android, android-widget

I am having some issues with the getting the size of a home screen widget I am designing. I've read the sdk documentation and done a bit of searching, but I'm not really finding anything useful. Anyway, I am using the onAppWidgetOptionsChanged method of the widget provider to get the widget size on devices above API 16, and it reports incorrectly on some devices. It functions correctly on a Nexus S and a Transformer Prime, but the values it gives on my S3 is smaller than what I measured from a screenshot. I have accounted for the fact that it is reported in dp instead of pixels. I'm guessing that there is some type of margin being added by Samsung's launcher, but I can't find any correlation. For example, when I use a 2x2 widget, onAppWidgetOptionsChanged reports 154dp (~293px) width and 193dp (~355px) height, but I measured ~340px by 420px in Photoshop. Is this a Samsung only problem, or am I going to face this on many non-vanilla platforms. The code is pretty basic, but I am posting any just in case.

```
@Override
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions) {
    int minWidth = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH);
    int maxWidth = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH);
    int minHeight = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT);
    int maxHeight = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT);

    Log.i("WidgetProvider","Widget size changed");
    Log.i("WidgetProvider","minWidth: " + minWidth);
    Log.i("WidgetProvider","minHeight: " + minHeight);
    Log.i("WidgetProvider","maxWidth: " + maxWidth);
    Log.i("WidgetProvider","maxHeight: " + maxHeight);
}
```

I am using the size reported to generate a bitmap in my widget update service. I need to use a custom bitmap because I want use custom fonts and backgrounds for my widget. On devices below API 16, I just set the bitmap to the minWidth and minHeight defined in the widget info xml. On some devices this leaves more padding than I would prefer around the widget, but the image is undistorted. As I understand, there is no way of getting the widget size in earlier devices. Also, I don't believe custom fonts can be used in a TextView in an app widget. Is this correct? I have tried using fitXY with the image, but it just looks horrible on some devices. Is there any more predictable way of accomplishing custom background and custom font on a widget? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'me pretty sure there's no predictable way to get sizes across all devices and launchers. In particular, Samsung TouchWiz has its own rules regarding padding. Take a look at http://radleymarx.com/blog/app-widget-padding-margins-in-ics-android/

Answer (score 2):

It looks that I have the samr problem. Widget 4*4 at Galaxy Note. onAppWidgetOptionsChanged return me 426*384 max sizes but if you see at screen the height is more than width...

Comment: Thanks for the input. Are you by chance looking at both maxWidth and maxHeight? If so, I'm pretty sure that you need to look at one max and one min dimension for a given screen orientation. For most devices, the maximum width and minimum height will be used in landscape mode, while maximum height and minimum width will be used in portrait mode. I made this mistake when I first started trying to use this method.